# How to remove a node where isn't a specific field from xml in groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

is it possible to remove a node if there isn't a field inside ?

This an example of xml:

```
    <nodes xmlns:d="www.test.com" xmlns:m="www.type.com">
        <m:node>
            <d:id>1</d:id>
        </m:node>
        <m:node>
            <d:id>2</d:id>
            <d:status>ok</d:status>
        </m:node>
    </nodes>
```

This is the result I need to have:

```
<nodes xmlns:d="www.test.com" xmlns:m="www.type.com">
    <m:node>
         <d:id>2</d:id>
         <d:status>ok</d:status>
    </m:node>
</nodes>
```

This is the code I tried:

```
String myxml = """
<nodes xmlns:d='ww.test.com' xmlns:m='www.type.com'>
  <m:node>
     <d:id>1</d:id>
  </m:node>
  <m:node>
     <d:id>2</d:id>
     <d:status>ok</d:status>
  </m:node>
</nodes>
"""

def xml=new XmlParser().parseText(myxml)

def nodeToDel=xml.nodes.node.find { it.'d:status'.text() == '' }
if (nodeToDel != null){
    nodeToDel.print(nodeToDel);
    parent = nodeToDel.parent()
    parent.remove(nodeToDel)
}
```

Could you help me to remove that node with empty field?

Thanks
Bais

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
def xml = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(myxml)

xml.'m:node'.each {
    if (!it.'d:status'?.text()) {
        xml.remove(it)
    }
}

new XmlNodePrinter(System.out.newPrintWriter()).with {
    preserveWhitespace = true
    it.print(xml)
}
```

It prints the result xml to System.out...  If you need it in a file or something, you need to create a PrintWriter, and pass it as the argument to the XmlNodePrinter constructor